# I need a simple example of when to use non-virtual multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I teach C++, and I need a good, simple, everyday example of when you would use this:

```
class A {...};
class B : public A {...};
class C : public A {...};
class D : public B, public C {...};
```

Here D inherits A twice because there is no virtual inheritance involved.

I need an easy-to-understand motivational example of when you might need this construct. I don't even need code for it; I just need to be able to present an example to my students so they exclaim, "Yes, I can see that that would be useful!"

Comment: Why would you convince them that this could be useful? IMHO, this is not important at all. They will practically never see this on EARTH. Even the example of the Queen is not that correct.

Comment: "The queen inherits from the bishop and the rook" this is not a good example of an *is-a* relationship.

Comment: I agree with @AhmadWabbi that it is a rare construct; but students will ask why C++ supports both virtual and non-virtual inheritance.

Comment: `boost::uncopyable` as base, which in turn is a base?

Comment: I think a simple example will be a theoretical system user class.
A = User, 
B = User : Admin, 
C = User : Regular, 
D = User, Admin, Regular : Sudo. D is a User an Admin and a Regular user. D is godlike.

Comment: "good, simple, everyday example" and "multiple inheritance" ...urrhhh....

Comment: @KakamiOkatsu I wouldn't implement that as inheritance

Comment: It's supports virtual inheritance because sometimes nothing else will work. It supports non-virtual inheritance because 99.9% of the time (that you should use inheritance all, which isn't all that common), that's what you want.

Comment: non-virtual and multiple inheritance are separate features which do not need to have a combined use-case. For example you will rarely need a non-virtual deconstructor as well...

Comment: @KakamiOkatsu, surely your example requires virtual inheritance. You don't want D to hold user information twice.

Comment: @oz1cz you could assume that a User belong to a System Group. And Sudo belong to both the groups.

Comment: Please, people, before you comment, make sure you know the difference between a virtual function and virtual class inheritance.

Comment: You wan't an "easy-to-understand example" or a "real life commit on Github code"? In my opinion if it's a learning example the only purpose is to make clear the concept to the class.

Comment: @Danh Write that as an answer. All the examples with strange taxonomies are OO mistakes

Comment: @oz1cz "_make sure you know the difference between a virtual function and virtual class inheritance_" and the similarities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this example for both virtual and non-virtual multiple inheritance:

A --> Person (id, name)

B --> Teacher (salary)

C --> Student (marks)

D --> AssitantTeacher

For me, an AssistantTeacher is a freshly-graduated teacher who is teaching and preparing a higher degree (Masters or PhD). He has a salary as well as marks.

To add non-virtual flavor, suppose that teachers have ids in a specific format, and students have ids in other format. An AssistantTeacher has two ids: one teacher id (that is used as a primary key in the HR database) and one student id (that is used as a PK in the academic system database).

[EDIT]

As an example, the HR ERP system would give an auto-increment id to teachers, and the academic students system would give students ids of the format: YYYYMMSAAAA (where Y is the year of enrollment of the student, M is the month, S is the sex: 0 or 1, and A is an auto-increment id part).

An AssistantTeacher may have the id "1332" in the HR system and "20170100004" as a student id.

Comment: If `id` is specific, it should probably go in `Teacher`/`Student`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Every person has an id, but the format is specific and different in the two classes. An AssistantTeacher has two different ids at the same time

Comment: A Teacher can be a Student, and vice versa.

Comment: @Peter This is expressed by the `AssistantTeacher` class: this is for persons who are teachers AND students at the same time

Comment: @AhmadWabbi - not so.    Imagine an English teacher who goes to a class to learn differential calculus.

Comment: @Peter OK then replace the name `AssistantTeacher` by `StudingTeacher`. He still has twi ids

Comment: IMO this is not a good OO design. Having different id formats breaks the Liskov substitution principle. Not to mention the Janus-like assistant teacher (double-named).

Comment: @AMA Yeah true, but it is nearly impossible to find a cleaner example of non-virtual multiple inheritance. This is really an artificial pedagogic example to motivate this concept. See my first comment on the question: I already suggested not to mention this at all to the students. I teach and I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short version:** multiple non-virtual inheritance in a diamond configuration **is** **never** **useful**.

---

**Longer version:**
The situation you are describing here is known as [the diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). This is exactly the situation that virtual inheritance aims to solve.

I understand what you mean with your question though, if something exists in the language this is certainly there because of some reasons. And it is useful for at least a very narrow range of situations. But I rather see the situation this way:

- Multiple inheritance (MI) exists in C++ and is useful for combining several interfaces in one
- Virtual MI exists in C++ and is useful for solving the diamond problem
- Non-virtual MI in a diamond configuration exists only as a side-effect of MI and is undesirable.

---

As for the virtual MI I like to use an example of separating interface- and implementation-hierarchies (or extending interfaces). E.g., when you have configurations like these:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe phrases like "_deadly diamond of death_" are helpful.

Comment: @curiousguy could you clarify? This is another name of the diamond problem, which is actually used (even mentioned in the wiki article). What is wrong with it?

Comment: It's a silly name. It's intended to provoke irrational fear and create the impression that MI creates very complex problems.

Comment: @curiousguy I actually agree. Not only C++ has the situation under control with the virtual MI, but diamond configuration can be even useful (as I tried to show with an example at the bottom). I also don't like the dogmatic opinion many C++ developers seem to share about it.  I removed the mention of DDD.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an easy question, because any discussion on it will lead to inheritance vs composition.

For an example of virtual inheritance, I will keep your chess example

```
                     Chess_piece
                      attributes: pos_x, pos_y;
                      / \
    _________________/   \___________________
   /                                         \
Bishop                                      Rook
 methods:                                    methods:    
  first_diagonal_move(length)                 horizontal_move(length)
  second_diagonal_move(length)                vertical_move(length)
  \__________________     ___________________/
                     \   /
                    Queen
```

And the Queen inherits from the methods of both Rook and Bishop, but the Queen has the attributes of only one single piece, so we will use C++ virtual inheritance here.

Next imagine that we build a composite geometric figure composed of one circle and one point. Here is an "inheritance" graph:

```
Point                             Point
 attributes: pos_x, posy           attributes: pos_x
    |                                 |
    |                                 |
Circle                                |
 attribute: radius                    |
     \___________     ________________/
                 \   /
                 Figure
```

Here the figure will have two distinct instances of Point so we shall not use virtual inheritance.

In fact, this happens because in second case, we try to use inheritance, where the correct pattern should be composition: the figure actually contains a Point and Circle. This kind of non virtual inheritance leads to complex questions such as *what is the position of the figure?*. For that reason OO advises to use the [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) rule.

But as it is discussed more in details in the above linked page, inheritance has *technical* goodies: the derived class has immediate access to its base classes methods while in the composition pattern, you must explicitely implements them even to build a simple forwarding implementation. In some cases, it leads to a lot of boiling platter code, and the more code, the higher cost is tests (or the more risk of mistakes if you do not...)

TL/DR: Multiple inheritance by itself is a complex pattern, that is not allowed for that reason in some post C++ languages such as Java. Non virtual multiple inheritance is generally a hint of pattern smell because inheritance was used where composition should have be. But if you know why you use it (avoiding code duplication **is** an acceptable reason) and you document it, it can be used. After all it is allowed by the C++ language...

Answer (score 0):

In C++, inheritance doesn't always mean subtyping, at least accessible subtyping: an inheritance relation has access control, just like member access.

Non virtual inheritance is an exclusive relation of inheritance. Virtual inheritance is a relation of inheritance that can be shared.

Non virtual inheritance is a strict relation between an object and its direct base classes, like membership is a strict relation between an object and its members. Virtual inheritance is a loose relation; in a way, virtual inheritance is never indirect. Every constructor initializes the direct bases and members, and information is transmitted, recursively, to constructors of bases subobjects and the innermost members; but the constructor of the most derived object directly initializes the virtual base classes.

Inheritance allows a derived class to override virtual functions. Because virtual inheritance is a shared relation, the responsibility of overriding base class virtual function is shared between several "sibling" classes; these siblings must be cooperate in how they override the (shared) virtual functions of the (shared) base class.

You should use non virtual inheritance whenever:

- initialization must be done directly by the immediate subclass, with specific parameters
- overriding by a "sibling" class would be inappropriate